# HTML5 semantic layout (div, article, section) and explicit identifiers

Tags: html, html5

I'm writing a markup for: 
[image]
And I've split it for these sections:

```
<header>
    <div id="logo"></div>
    <nav id="mainNav"></nav>    
</header>
<div id="banner"></div>
<div id="content">
    <section id="advantages">
        <section class="advantage"></section>
        <section class="advantage"></section>
        <section class="advantage"></section>
        <section class="advantage"></section>
    </section>
    <div id="main"></div>
    <aside></aside>
</div>
<footer>
    <div id="extra">
        <article class="extra"></article>
        <article class="extra"></article>
        <article class="extra"></article>
        <article class="extra"></article>
    </div>
    <div id="credit"></div>
</footer>
```

Is it semantically correct(`div`, `section`, `article`) and are my identifiers explicit?

Comment: The template is here: http://templates.websitetemplatesonline.com/Progress-business/index.html and I don't know if it's OK to rip it off like this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### `#logo` → `h1`

Your `<div id="logo"></div>` should be a `h1`, otherwise the document outline wouldn't be correct:

```
<h1><img id="logo" src="logo.png" alt="Progress Business Company"></h1>
```

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/14920215/1591669 for an explanation.

#### `#banner` → `header` or `aside`

If your `<div id="banner"></div>` doesn't contain main content, it should go in an `aside` element, or, if it can be understood as part of the header (probably on each page of the site), in the `header` element.

#### `#main` → `section` (or `article`)

Instead of `<div id="main"></div>` you could use a sectioning element here. I assume your `div` contains a heading ("Welcome, dear visitor!"), so you have something like an implict section anyhow. Why not make it explicit? So use a `section` instead of the `div` (depending on the actual content, `article` might be suitable instead).

#### `#content > aside` → `section`

I'd say on the front page the testimonials *could* be considered part of the main content (in the end it depends on the real content/context), so instead of `aside` you could use `section` then.

Each single testimonial should be in its own `article`, of course.

#### `#extra > article` → `section`

I don't think `article` elements in the `footer` are suitable for that kind of content (unless your actual page contains something different). (Only the newsletter form could possibly get `article` instead of `section`, but that's not that clear; personally I'd use `section` for it, too).

So, I'd go with `section` here. If the contact details listed under "Address" are relevant for the whole page, you should use the `address` element, too.

```
<div id="extra">
    <section class="extra"></section>
    <section class="extra">
      <h1>Address</h1>
      <address>…</address>
    </section>
    <section class="extra"></section>
    <section class="extra"></section>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

After writing html structure, I explicitly check for at least two things.

- Are there any `div`s that can go away?
- Can I remove any `class` or `id`?

Let's try to apply this to your code:

```
<header>
    <div id="logo"></div>
    <nav id="mainNav"></nav>    
</header>
```

You can replace `<div id="logo"></div>` whith `<h1>Progress Business Company</h1>`. Your CSS will hide the text anyway, but it will be visible for people that don't see the logo (images disabled or screen reader).

```
<div id="banner"></div>
```

This one seems OK, but keep my advices in mind when you feel it.

```
<div id="content">
```

What about `<article>`?

```
    <section id="advantages">
        <section class="advantage"></section>
        <section class="advantage"></section>
        <section class="advantage"></section>
        <section class="advantage"></section>
    </section>
```

You don't need all those `class` here. In CSS, `#advantages section` will select your subsections and will make explicit the relation between the big section and the subsections. This also frees your HTML from unnecessary clutter.

```
    <div id="main"></div>
    <aside></aside>
```

This applies to the rest of the HTML and could be the most important remark: the image you're trying to integrate has been designed with a **grid** in mind. See how the A, B, C, D subsections are laid out? How "Testimonials" aligns with D? And so on. Using a grid such as Bootstrap or 960 grid will help you a lot here.

```
<div id="extra">
    <article class="extra"></article>
    <article class="extra"></article>
    <article class="extra"></article>
    <article class="extra"></article>
</div>
```

Same issue than with "advantages".

```
<div id="credit"></div>
```

What about a paragraph (`p`) instead of a `div`?